# The likelihood function of related samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood, independence

I know how to get the likelihood function for two independent samples from normal distribution. What will happen to the likelihood function if the samples are related? What will be its form?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you mean by related but for example they can be correlated so that:
$$
y_1=\mu_1+\epsilon_1 \Sigma_{1,1} + \epsilon_c \Sigma_{1,2},
$$
$$
y_2=\mu_2+\epsilon_2 \Sigma_{2,2} + \epsilon_c \Sigma_{2,1}.
$$
where $\epsilon_1 \sim N(0,1)$, $\epsilon_2 \sim N(0,1)$ and $\epsilon_c \sim N(0,1)$ independent and with $\Sigma_{i,j}$ positive real values. Here it is easy to see that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are related in a certain form: they both depend on the gaussian noise term $\epsilon_c$. This noise model can be rewritten as: 
$$
[y_1,y_2] \sim N(\mu,\Sigma) 
$$
where $N$ stands here for the multivariate normal distribution with mean $\mu$ (here a 2d vector) and the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ (here a 2 by 2 positive definite symmetric matrix). Then from this well described distribution, the likelihood function simply writes:
$$
L(\mu,\sigma;y=[y_1,y_2])=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{2}|\Sigma|}}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}({ y}-{\mu})^{T}{\Sigma}^{-1}({ y}-{\mu})
\right).
$$